# What's the meaning of multiple from selectors in a LINQ query

Tags: .net, sql, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-query-syntax

I've seen multiple from clauses in a LINQ query a few times now, but have not figured out how that corresponds to a TSQL statement.

```
var r = from p in products
        from d in departments
        from c in something
        select p;
```

**What does that do?**

Does that translate to SQL as `SELECT * FROM products, departments, something`?

**Also, the `select` in this case is supposed to always be a `SelectMany`. how do I know when a `select` actually is a `SelectMany`?**

Comment: (this isn't intended to be as aggressive as it sounds) "how do I know when a select actually is a SelectMany" - why do you care?

Answer (score 3):

That will translate into code conceptually like this:

```
var r = products.SelectMany(p => departments, (p, d) = new { p, d })
                .SelectMany(z => something, (z, c) => new { z, c })
                .Select(zz => zz.z.p);
```

Basically each `from` after the first one adds an extra call to `SelectMany`. Actually, in this case the compiler will notice that after the last `from` clause there's just a `select`, and it will *actually* translate to this:

```
var r = products.SelectMany(p => departments, (p, d) = new { p, d })
                .SelectMany(z => something, (z, c) => z.p);
```

... but I tend to think of the "logical" form first.

Note that in this case you haven't used the earlier range variables within the `from` clauses, but you can:

```
var query = from person in people
            from friend in person.Friends
            select person.Name + " is friends with " + friend.Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

> How that corresponds to a TSQL statement?

It depends on the way how you use your `from` clauses. If you use:

```
var query = from d in context.Departments
            from e in context.Employees
            select d;
```

Your query will be `CROSS JOIN` because there is no relation between product and department used. So something like:

```
SELECT d.* FROM Departments AS d
CROSS JOIN Employees AS e
```

Obviously you should avoid cross joins. If you instead use navigation property in second `from`:

```
var query = from d in context.Departments
            from e in d.Employees
            select d;
```

you will use either `INNER` or `LEFT JOIN` (EF will decide which one to use based on your multiplicity mapping in the relation). So something like:

```
SELECT d.* FROM Departments AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees AS e ON d.Id = e.DepartmentId
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it doesn't make any sense to use select (it's not semantically correct, you must use SelectMany)